# delete emp table data using ssis package

Tags: postgresql, ssis, ssis-2012, postgresql-9.4

I want delete the data in the target server(postgres) tables data using ssis package.

```
database : postgres server 
Table : emp
in execute sql task :scriptis:  delete from emp and connection used odbc
```

when i run the executesql task in ssis package
if emp table have data then its working fine and i am getting the error when emp table donot have data.

> [Execute SQL Task] Error: Executing the query "delete from  emp
>   usin..." failed with the following error: "Error HRESULT E_FAIL has been returned from a call to a COM component.". Possible failure reasons: Problems with the query, "ResultSet" property not set correctly, parameters not set correctly, or connection not established correctly.

suppose if i run same query in pgadmin tool  that time it is not getting any error even though emp table donot have data.

how to avoid this issue in ssis package?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, The DELETE statement contains the connection. I guess you have passed the ODBC connection manager to the Execute SQL Task properties - Connection Type and Connection. Then your SQL script could be just:
DELETE FROM emp;

[SSIS - Execute SQL Task Editor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kQIQ4.png)